# How to efficiently self-join so the query does not time out?

Tags: sql-server

```
  | id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | val1 | val2 | age | race | zip | 
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  | 11  | 222 | 333 | 44  | 789  | abc  |  45 |  AA  |12345|
  | 11  | 222 | 333 | 44  | 567  | def  |  45 |  AA  |12345|
  | 11  | 333 | 444 | 44  | 789  | xyz  |  30 |  AS  |23456|
  | 22  | 555 | 666 | 77  | 012  | abc  |  38 |   W  |34567|
  | 22  | 555 | 666 | 77  | 789  | GHI  |  38 |   W  |34567|
  | 34  | 333 | 777 | 99  | 012  | GHI  |  75 |   W  |34567|
```

I want to get ALL rows for ID1, id2, id3, id4 where val1 is 789. So the output look similar to this:

```
  | id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | val1 | val2 | age | race | zip |
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  | 11  | 222 | 333 | 44  | 789  | abc  |  45 |  AA  |12345|
  | 11  | 222 | 333 | 44  | 567  | def  |  45 |  AA  |12345|
  | 11  | 333 | 444 | 44  | 789  | xyz  |  30 |  AS  |23456|
  | 22  | 555 | 666 | 77  | 012  | abc  |  38 |   W  |34567|
  | 22  | 555 | 666 | 77  | 789  | GHI  |  38 |   W  |34567|
```

I can get the self-join to work on a small dataset, however since the table I'm working is huge, I want an efficient solution that will not timeout. Here is the query I'm using:

```
 select  t1.*
  from t t1
     join t t2 on 
            t1.id1=t2.id1 and
            t1.id2=t2.id2 and
            t1.id3=t2.id3 and
            t1.id4=t2.id4 
   where t1.val1='789'
```

Again, I want ALL rows of ID1 through ID4 as long as one of the VAL1 value is '789'.

Comment: Your results don't seem to correspond to your question. If you want help with your code, you'll need to show us your code, show us the results, and explain how the results differ from your desired results.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: added the query I used, but it times out on a large table.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments on the answer to your [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67246724/selecting-all-rows-of-col1-when-where-condition-matches-one-value-of-colb/67246977) the performance will be primarily due to your table schema and indexing, add your query's actual execution plan [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: Self-join on 4 integer fields with filtering by string  field by itself must be quite efficient if it's supported by indexes. So first I would look on plans  - are indexes are OK or not.  Second - I would look for cardinality of data. Do you have multiple rows for  the same id1+id2+id3+id4? If so - EXISTS instead of JOIN is needed.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question You need to share the query plan if you want help on performance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join to any tables - what you want is EXISTS:

```
Select *
  From t   t1
 Where Exists (Select *
                 From t   t2
                Where t1.ID1 = t2.ID1
                  And t2.val1 = 789)
```